# Why sublime text and VSCode not showing runtime error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

In the below code snippet, for example, take n as 9 and the array a's elements as {5,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,6}.
Sublime text and visual studio code are showing the correct output as 3 but [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/) online ide is showing "runtime error: index 8 out of bounds for type 'int [k]' ". I want to know why sublime text and visual studio code are not showing the runtime error, and if there is an ide/text editor which shows runtime error, please recommend it to me.

```
    int k = n - 1;
    int temp[k];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < k ; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = (a[i] - a[i + 1]);
    }
    int res = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < k ; )
    {
        int x = temp[i];
        int c = 0;
        while (x == temp[i])
        {
            i++;
            c++;
        }
        res = max(res, c + 1);
    }
    cout<<res;
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour, so technically there is no correct output (`a[i + 1]` is out of bounds on the last iteration). Apparently, Leetcode does bounds checking on arrays. You'll need to find a compiler and runtime that has that feature. What editor you're using doesn't matter.

Comment: An index out of bounds error is an example of an error that causes *undefined behaviour*. Because the behaviour is undefined both Leetcode and your compiler are correct. You should not expect bad programs to behave in predictable ways. It's one of the things that makes C++ programming hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int k = n - 1;
int temp[k];    // variable length array, must be either #define k <constant num>
                // or 'const int k'
```

The variable-length arrays (VLAs) aren't supported in C++ standard. The Sublime Text & VS Code doesn't matters at all, but the compiler.

You might've not enabled your compiler warnings, thus, you're unable to see any error. You can do it by appending `-pedantic` flag in your compilation option to see all warnings.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I was using this type of declaration on arrays from a long time not knowing that this is incorrect.